# Fetch in Slim framework not doing what I expect

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make an API using the slim framework. Based upon a tutorial from the web, I have `index.php` which calls `dbHelper.php`. I am simply trying to get a list of all unique languages in a specific table. The query returns 1 result (as I only have one language loaded at present), however fetch returns `"true"`.

```
public function get_languages(){
    $response=array();

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT language, count(language)AS count FROM vocab GROUP BY language');
    $result=$stmt->execute();
    if($result){
        while($language_instance = $stmt->fetch()){
            array_push($response,$language_instance['language']);
        }
        array_push($response,$stmt);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $response;
}
```

The response array returns

```
[
        null,
        {
            "affected_rows": null,
            "insert_id": null,
            "num_rows": null,
            "param_count": null,
            "field_count": null,
            "errno": null,
            "error": null,
            "error_list": null,
            "sqlstate": null,
            "id": null
        }
    ]
```

When executing the query via `phpMyAdmin`, I get a single line with the correct values, so I assuming I am doing something fundamentally wrong within `Slim` however Mr. Google has so far been unhelpful.

Any pointers or link to appropriate documentation would be helpful.

Kind regards
Chris H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the fetch method is not what it appears, so I adjusted this to as follows and am now getting the results I want.

```
$result=$this->conn->query('SELECT language FROM vocab GROUP BY language');
while ($language_instance = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
    array_push($response,$language_instance['language']);
}
```

This does NOT answer my question regarding why fetch() does not return an array, however it solves my problem.